# How to enable local network traffic in the c# application manifest file?

Tags: c#

According to this. I need to enable local network traffic in the manifest file of c# application. Can anyone paste a sample code to enable it in application manifest file?

I tried to use fiddler proxy in httpclient however its not going to fiddler proxy. I stumbled upon this post and they says enable local network traffic in the manifest file https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce2563d1-cd96-4380-ad41-6b0257164130/winrt-using-httpclient-with-systems-proxy?forum=winappswithcsharp  any help appreciated.

Current my application manifest are the following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>

  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="6500" />
    </connectionManagement>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

httpclient code this request is not going through fiddler.

```
 string url_get_string = "http://localhost/php/tmp/test.php?Get_C="+ ID;
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        handler.CookieContainer = cookieJar;            
        handler.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888", false);
        handler.UseProxy = true;
        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;



        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: I think any traffic from your application should be visible directly to Fiddler except you set a proxy for it.

Comment: Try removing the proxy line, the request should usually go to fiddler automatic because Fiddler is changing the default proxy when it opens. Make sure that your fiddler settings doesn't have a problem.